# Missing Value error running an AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have written a little AppleScript which returns "missing value" and I have no idea why this happens. The script is doing what it should do, but the output is not nice in my application where I use it.

The principle of this script is just to take the argument and run the file (with "VLC Media Player") which is provided through the argument.

So for example a use would be `osascript open_video.scpt ~/Path/To/File/File.mp3`

```
on run argv
    tell application "VLC" 
        activate 
        open argv
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: can someone tell me how i can set a bounty on this question >.< it says the button for it has to be under the comment area of my question, but there is none :(

Comment: Maybe you didn't have enough reputation points at the time? Can you add it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old but brought to the top of the questions by a new answer before I added this answer.

The recently posted answer suggests this issue might be caused if there isn't an ending *newline* character, and this is not at all true in this case as I've tested both with and without an ending *newline* character and get the exact same results, both with compiled and plain text AppleScript scripts.

You do not need to have an ending *newline* character and it has nothing to do with why your *code* is returning `missing value`.

Looking in the AppleScript Dictionary for the `open` *command*, it shows the following:

**open** *v* : Open an object.
          **open** alias : The file(s) to be opened.
                → document

Where the **→** represents *returns* as in it returns info about the documents, e.g. its name.

In this case VLC is returning `missing value` instead, and probably because VLC does not integrate AppleScript as nice as e.g. Apple's own apps.

If you do not want to see `missing value` then add a `return ""` to the *code* and it will return a blank line. Or you could add e.g., `return "VLC is now playing: & (argv as string)`; however, because VLC's AppleScript integration is not the best, I'd just go with `return ""` as VLC does not respond to standard AppleScript error handling well. Again, an observation by testing  *error handling code* that works with other apps but not VLC.

**Or just simply directly use the command line `open` *command*, e.g:**

```
open "/Applications/VLC.app" "/path/to/media_file.ext"
```

Which will *open* the VLC app, *start* the `media_file.ext` *file*, and *return* the *prompt*.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, you have to coerce the passed variable to a string.

```
osascript open_video.scpt '~/Path/To/File/File.mp3'
```

with a script as such:

```
on run argv
    tell application "VLC" 
        activate 
        open (argv as string)
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: so for me this solution does not solve my problem, same output and also the playing does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you have a newline on the end of the last line?  For me I got this error when I had a script that ended abruptly at the last character of the script, instead of having a newline at the end.

AFAIK this doesn't affect the functionality of your script, just what it returns.  In my case I got some other output instead after I made this change, but the output appeared to be merely informational.

Comment: In this case, one does not need to have an ending _newline_ character and it has nothing to do with why his _code_ is returning `missing value`. See my answer for details.